# Motor control using ROS, Epos2 and CANOpen

Tags: ros, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I happen to be stuck for a few days now by problems some of the forum's members apparently already encountered, whence this question. I hope the latter will not be considered as superfluous, and that it could prove to be helpful to others.

My computer runs a 64-bit Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) OS, and ROS Noetic Ninjemys (`rosversion -d` says `noetic`). I besides installed the package "ros_canopen" from the "package.ros.org" repositories using `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-ros-canopen`.

My current goal is to manage to send rotation speed commands to an AC motor equipped with a Hall sensor (similar to [this model](https://www.harmonicdrive.net/products/rotary-actuators/hollow-shaft-actuators/fha-mini)) through an [EPOS2 70/10](https://www.maxongroup.com/maxon/view/product/control/Positionierung/375711?etcc_cu=onsite&etcc_med=Header%20Suche&etcc_cmp=mit%20Ergebnis&etcc_ctv=Layer&query=epos2) electric drive, using the CANOpen communication protocol, and thus, the "ros_canopen" package. My problem is that I actually don't know where to start to achieve such objective.

After some researches, I ended up trying to follow the steps proposed [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/250174/how-to-control-maxon-motor-by-using-ros_canopen/) on the forum. I was though not even able to complete the first stage, consisting in setting-up SocketCAN. I met indeed two issues:

1. When loading the drivers, the command `sudo modprobe pcan` returns `modprobe: FATAL: Module pcan not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64`
2. When running `sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000`, which says `sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 1000000`. The device "can0" does besides not appear in the list provided by `ifconfig -a`.

Could you please give me a clue about how to overcome those problems ?

An additional difficulty may come from the fact that I have chosen thus far to connect the EPOS2 controller to my computer using its USB output only. I do not employ any CAN-to-USB interface, simply because I do not have one to hand for now. Is such a device necessary to perform motor control ?

Could you finally please recommend me a tutorial, or give me pieces of advice, regarding motor control using the "ros_canopen" package.

Thanks a lot, regards,

Julien.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358180/motor-control-using-ros,-epos2-and-canopen/) by [JulienTemplai](https://answers.ros.org/users/50005/julientemplai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

first you should have a usb-can dev and it could support pcan. For example,pcan-usb.After  installing the driver, then  you can use  ifconfig -a  to check  can0  which exists or not . When you find can0, it shows that you install the driver correctly.
Here is the website you can refer:http://www.peak-system.com/fileadmin/media/linux/version-history.html

---

Originally posted by [HHHCMH](https://answers.ros.org/users/57413/hhhcmh/) with karma: 26 on 2020-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JulienTemplai](https://answers.ros.org/users/50005/julientemplai/) on 2020-08-07**:
Thank you for your answer.
If I understand you correctly, a CAN-USB interface (such as [this one](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-USB.199.0.html?&L=2)) is definitely required to perform motor control using the "ros_canopen" package, isn't it ?
I will besides check the Peak System's website as you suggested.